# Is there some search result sorting like: `most popular`?

Tags: search-results

I have a `ContentBySearchWebPart` configured with this query:

```
{searchboxquery} Path:http://myCompany.com/sv contentclass:"STS_Site"
```

I selected some display template and it looks good. Is it possible to implement some sorting? I would like to show the most populair site collections as first. I mean with populair the most hits/visitors on these site collections.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the `Sorting` tab of the webparts "Change query" menu (you need to enter advanced mode to find the sorting tab) set `Sort by` to `ViewsRecent` `Descendant`.

This will sort your result on the number of views it has had in the last 14 days (the nubmer of views is by default calculated once a day by a timer job)

Comment: thanks, is there also another way to get the most views from always and not last 14 days?

Comment: `ViewsLifeTime` if I'm not remembering wrong

Comment: @RobertLindgren I need to configure for SharePoint online where ViewsRecent is not working in my case. Since ViewsRecent(Manage Property is not mapped to any crawled property).. Please help me on this

Comment: @praveen this should work fine online as well...